# jQuery AJAX function - Chrome throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jsonp

I have a number of clickable objects on the screen that represent objects within a piece of software being interfaced through a COM component.

When I click on an object I send the name of the object, the session ID and the command I want to run.

The code for the particular command that I'm trying to implement is a C# based ASP.NET page:

```
case "myClick":
                dynamic simObj = S8COM.get_SimObject(Request["id"]);
                responseData = "{name:" + simObj.Name.ToString() + ",countInRoutes:" + simObj.CountInRoutes.ToString() + ",countOutRoutes:" + simObj.CountOutRoutes.ToString() + ",index:" + simObj.Index.ToString() + ",capacity:" + simObj.Capacity.ToString() + ",completed:" + simObj.Completed.ToString() + ",routeOutMethod:" + simObj.RouteOutMethod.ToString() + "}";
                break;
```

This works fine for some objects, but not others, throwing an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" exception.

The JS I use to call this particular function is:

```
S8Web.Requestmanager.makeRequest({ data: { command: "myClick", id: aItem.id }, async: true, callback: function(data){
                        alert(data.CountInRoutes); //Do a vardump of the response
                        }});
```

A couple of responses as well, the first one works fine, whereas the second throws the Unexpected Number exception:

```
jsonp1319203225074({name:Start,countInRoutes:0,countOutRoutes:1,index:5,capacity:0,completed:0,routeOutMethod:4});

jsonp1319203225066({name:Process 1,countInRoutes:1,countOutRoutes:1,index:1,capacity:1,completed:0,routeOutMethod:1});
```

The only thing I can see that could possibly affect the outcome is the whitespace between "Process" and "1".  Is that what is throwing this error?

Comment: is it only in the chrome browser that throws this error?

Comment: yep... since it is a string you need to wrap it in quotes.. `name:'Process 1'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You very well may simply be having a problem with improperly closed quotes.

Example:

```
<a href='#' onclick="doStuff('joe, '2844')">click here</a>
```

Since the first parameter isn't closed properly, it's being interpreted as *'joe, '*. That leaves *2844'* as the rest of the function call, without a leading quote. This circumstance will throw the Unexpected Number error.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this will help you, but I was getting the same error in chrome and it was because of a "0" that trailed my json data:

```
{id: "6"}0
```

The 0 trailed the JSON data because I forgot to add an "exit;" in my PHP function that was handling the AJAX call. I also recommend running the same code in FireFox. FireFox a lot of the times has more informative error messages than chrome:

> Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I added `die()` at the end of my PHP function and that resolved the `SyntaxError: unexpected number` issue!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the cause of the error, but consider letting a serializer do the work instead of hand coding. Might help take care of different interpretations in browsers.

In this example, I have a struct with string properties param1 + param2. You could easily serialize lists of these as well.

Just construct a simple struct that has the properties you need.

```
            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonApp = new StringBuilder();
            MyStruct item = new MyStruct();
            item.param1 ="111";
            item.param2 ="222";
            jss.Serialize(item, jsonApp); 
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
            var resp = HttpContext.Current.Request["callback"] + "(" + jsonApp.ToString() + ")";
            Response.Write(resp);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

also had a "0" in my if statement causing unexpected syntax: unexpected number in Chrome, comparison was:

`if (bcn.length==0 && ecn.length==0 0 && corr.length==0)`

extra 0, see it? I didn't catch it the first few glances.